# Table view doesn't store data

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a problem of storing data on table view.

It's a menu app that has a button which will pop over a table view and display them all the dishes they've ordered, I'm using the NSMutableArray to store the data, however whenever I close the table view, the data in the table will be reset to the initial status, which is the empty table.

What should I do to solve this issue, thanks for any help!

I'm using the FPPopover library to show the pop over table view, here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)revealOrderList:(id)sender
{
    SAFE_ARC_RELEASE(popover); popover=nil;

    OrderListViewController *controller = [[OrderListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    SAFE_ARC_RELEASE(controller); controller=nil;

    popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:nc];
    popover.tint = FPPopoverDefaultTint;
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 500);
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];
}
```

And in the pop over table view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    orderList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

    //add the add button
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)insertNewObject
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add new thing"
                                                message:@""
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    //Set the style of UIAlertView
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    //Show the UIAlertView
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Add some code?  If you unload the view controller the data is going with it.

Comment: Your primary problem is that you are relying on either the view or the controller to persist the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not stored by itself. You can input your initial data in the array but to save new data you need either core data or in another way use `NSUserDefaults` to save the new data to in a file or to a data base. Tim roadley has a great set of tutorial that deals with core data here is the link : http://timroadley.com/tutorials-index/

It also depends on the amount of data you are trying to save. If it is huge amount then SQL data base would better. Try either `NSUserDefaults` or the core data. But by just setting an array you can not save new data. The array will only show the original data you imputed in it through code. Also apple has a very good example of saving data. Try searching for the sample code Bird Watching. Better yet here is the link : http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/ipad/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: You are quiet welcome my friend. While studying these methods also look up how to write into a plist and how to read it as well. It might come handy for smaller projects. Happy coding my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the table view does initially store the data correctly, I imagine that you have the table view wired up correctly to the data source. If I had to guess why the data is disappearing, then, it would be that when you close the table, you release its controller, and thus its data. I would suggest allowing initial data to be passed to the table's controller when it is opened.

If this is not the case, posting some relevant code could really help to find an answer.